# How to display data betwen current date and current date+2month [Postgresql]

Tags: postgresql

I want to display all the rows betwen current date and current date+2 month, I used this query but not show me any line included in that interval but it only display  result of a specific date 01.10.2016 which is the off that I want to show the whole line that are in this range that is to say 11/11/2015, 12/11 /2015.......10/01/2016 here is my request

```
 select * 
 from calcul 
 where dateper = CURRENT_DATE+'2 month'::interval
```

Comment: I think you are looking for `where dateper between current_date and current_date + interval '2' month`

Comment: select * 
 from calcul 
 where dateper > CURRENT_DATE and dateper< CURRENT_DATE+'3 month'::interval